# My first Android app crashes when rotated

Tags: android

My app crashes whenever I rotate the Nexus from portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait.  It produces the exception report below, which I do not understand.

I basically did what it said, and found my main activity onDestroy function and added super.onDestroy, which made the problem go away.

However, why did this happen?  Why is onDestroy coming into play just because I rotated my tablet?

```
02-18 00:43:28.504  28259-28259/com.mpr.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mpr.myfirstapp, PID: 28259
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.mpr.myfirstapp/com.mpr.myfirstapp.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3889)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Add **super.onDestroy()** in your **onDestroy()** method.

Comment: Activities are destroyed and recreated when the device is rotated; read up on the Activity lifecycle.  Make sure that any time you override a method from the Activity class, you always call the super method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found here:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

What you are experiencing is essentially the default behaviour of an Android activity. When a change in orientation occurs, the resources tied with the Activity are subject to change and need to be managed. These kind of situations are usually handled with the `onSaveInsatanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods and their usage is highlighted in the documentation.

Answer (score 25):

Open your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add this attribute to your activity:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" />
```

The activity may recreated when you rotate the screen without add `orientation` value.

Comment: This worked for me on an app I'm working on. The previous developer had super.onDestroy() in the onDestroy() method but the app was still crashing when I rotated on a particular activity after I added some variables and methods to the Java file that accessed a TexttView with findById(). 

This was a real lifesaver. Thank you.

Comment: Seriously, This fixed it for me? Why?

Comment: I know this is a super old question, but this is not the way to fix this problem and it shows up very high on Google searches. Android recreates the activity on rotation. This forces Android to not recreate it, but the same recreation can happen for other reasons, like the user switching apps.

The above "fix" is mainly for things like video games, where you can't be expected to store the entire state in the milliseconds before a rotation event and resume

Answer (score 4):

The `Activity` is destroyed prior to rotation. It is then created again in the new orientation.

> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation
>   of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

It's an implementation detail. It is thoroughly [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()).

> protected void onDestroy ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Perform any final cleanup before an activity is
>   destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing
>   (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily
>   destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can
>   distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.
>
> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.
>
> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation
>   of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

By looking your logs I assume you have `onDestroy()` method written as following,

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
}
```

Actually you forgot to call `super.onDestroy();` inside the `onDestroy()` method, so actually your `onDestroy()` method should looks like below,

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();               // Add this line
}
```

This should solve your problem.